# How to apply spam filter into signatures?

Tags: advertising

The [spam](http://drupal.org/project/spam) module, does not seem to examine [forum signatures](http://drupal.org/project/signature_forum) against custom spam filters. Spammers have figured this out and just pour their junk links into their signatures. I am wondering how can I fix this loophole.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the content that passes the spam module filter is posted by bots. In that case, using one of the following modules (maybe in addition to the Spam module) may help (by letting the bots fill in hidden forms):

- [Honeypot](http://drupal.org/project/honeypot)
- [Botcha](http://drupal.org/project/botcha)

Comment: I am afraid they are human spammers and know how to deal with spam filters.

Comment: In that case I guess you'll have to extend the spam module to work with forum signatures. I don't know how hard that would be. Maybe file a feature request in the issue queue?